# Automatically inserting tags before saving post with a HABTM relationship

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've got a system set up where a post can have many tags and vice versa. This is a HABTM relationship. Everything works fine, and there's a input box for me to select the relevant tags when adding a post.

However I would like to implement a system like StackOverflow's where if I type in a tag that doesn't already exist, Cake first creates that tag in my `tags` table before saving the post (along with the relationship in the join table).

The only way I've found to do this is [outlined here](http://mrphp.com.au/blog/working-habtm-form-data-cakephp) (scroll down to "HABTM Text Add") where I manually check if the tag exists and if not, I insert it. I was wondering if Cake has a "built in" way of doing this, or there's a better way that conforms with Cake's "fat model slim controller" convention.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be using a [Model callback method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html). This would allow you to say, in your `afterSave()` to lookup the tag, then add it, and then save the new data.

Because you are working in your model, you will still have access to the models data using `$this->data`